# Mount a drive as to avoid "Disk not ejected properly"

Tags: usb

I am developing with a device that interacts with my mac as a USB drive. When uploading a program, the device will automatically disconnect itself and reset. Because of this, my mac thinks a drive has been forcefully disconnected (without ejecting first), causing it to throw the "Disk not ejected properly" error. How can I avoid this error?

Thank you!

Comment: It can't interact as a drive. Either that or on your reset, have it send an unmount command.

Comment: I am unable to run `umount` because the drive (which is a DAPLINK drive btw) will do all of the disconnecting and resetting on it's own after it receives a program.

Comment: Then manually unmount the disk (it will still be connected, but not mounted).  `diskutil unmountDisk diskX` where "X" is the identifier of your disk.  Then issue the reset.

Comment: I was really hopeful for that to work, but running the command will make the disk inaccessible (even to `cp` or `mv` something in). Is there any other way? If not, is it safe to just ignore the warning?

Comment: Why would you attempt to run a file command (`cp` or `mv`) on a device *after* you issue a reset?  Do you file ops, unmount, then reset....  Safe?  If you're not writing to it, you likely will get away with it but... (standard disclaimer here).  I would get with the dev of the device you're using and see what they say.

Comment: I'll probably just go talk to the developers of the device. Thanks for your help today!